# How to send emails with large attachments using gmail client API on Android

Tags: android, email, gmail-api

I've tried the following code to create multipart email with large attachments :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

MimeBodyPart mimeBodyText = new MimeBodyPart();
mimeBodyText.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
mimeBodyText.setContent(body, "text/html");

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(mimeBodyText);

if (attachments != null && attachments.size() > 0) {
    for (Uri uri : attachments) {
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        String fileName = UriUtils.getFileName(uri, context);
        String mimeType = UriUtils.getMimeType(uri, context);
        Log.d(TAG, "Generating file info, uri=" + uri.getPath() + ", mimeType=" + mimeType);
        FileInputStream is = UriUtils.generateFileInfo(context, uri, mimeType);
        if (is == null) {
            throw new MessagingException("Failed to get file for uri=" + uri.getPath());
        }
        try
        {
            mimeBodyAttachment.setFileName(fileName);
            mimeBodyAttachment.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType + "; name=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(is, mimeType);
            mimeBodyAttachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            mimeBodyAttachment.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
            mimeBodyAttachment.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
            mp.addBodyPart(mimeBodyAttachment);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MessagingException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
mimeMessage.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
mimeMessage.setContent(mp);

Message message = createMessageWithEmail(mimeMessage);

service.users().messages().send(from, message).execute();
```

Which is pretty similar to what is presented in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending), however, when I try to add a file which is larger than ~5mb, the execute function hangs and doesn't return (I would expect an error or at least a timeout but this is another issue)

After some search, I've found I need to somehow do `upload` request ([see here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads)), the following API in the `Gmail API` looks right :

```
Send send(java.lang.String userId, com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message content, com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any doc or instruction about its usage.
When I tried to put the attachment raw as `mediaContent` I got an error saying the only supported mime type is `message/rfc822`, so I've tried taking the `MimeBodyPart` I'm creating in the `for` loop above and use it, but it looks like the attachment is just ignored.

How should one use the `Gmail client API` and 'upload' attachments ?

Comment: Did you read this : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Comment: @pratz9999 yes I did, but this refers to the http request while I'm asking about the client API which should ease the use of the API.

Comment: https://github.com/steveholt55/JavaMail-API-Android
 may it will be more helpful

Comment: @pratz9999 thanks for the assistance, I started by using SMTP but since Google "offer" a nice `Gmail API` I thought it would be nicer to use it, unfortunately like many of their API's, the documentation is awful and unless you need the best practice, you will need some 3rd party assistance to make it work.

Comment: I agree with you on this. While working on many google API i had to take 3rd party support for more enhancement and improvement.

Comment: @pratz9999, just found the SMTP method doesn't work with 2-phase verification so in my opinion, it is not a solution :\...

Comment: Then I presume that you still looking for the answer! right ?

Comment: @pratz9999 right... still no solution :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question is a couple of months old, but after running into the same problem, I was able to figure it out.

My implementation is very similar to yours, all I changed was the last two lines.

So instead of using:

```
Message message = createMessageWithEmail(mimeMessage);

service.users().messages().send(from, message).execute();
```

Use:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mimeMessage.writeTo(bytes);

ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent("message/rfc822", bytes.toByteArray());
service.users().messages().send(from, null, content).execute();
```

Comment: 2 years later are better than ever. this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Upload/Download](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-upload) section of the Java client for Google API indicates the steps to do this.

Its indicated that you'll need to use `resumable media upload` as the upload option for this scenario. To implement it, you'll need to use `MediaHttpUploader` and `MediaUttpProgressListener`.

The referenced page also has an example that can work on GMail if you pass the `InputStreamContent` in the 3rd parameter of `send()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I need `MediaHttpUploader` or its progress listener, as you will see in the first example you provided, the first example uses the service-specific generated library to do the same behind the scenes, which is what the `Send()` API does, the problem is, when I provide the media type (i.e. `image/jpeg`) I get an error : `Media type 'image/jpeg' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822]`

Comment: Update: I've tried using the 3rd argument for the attachments in `[message/rfc822]` format but they are not being attached, I've also using the 3rd argument for the whole message with its attachments but I get bounce message saying the message wasn't sent.

Comment: I also believe Media Upload is for a different use-case, i.e. asking the Gmail API to fetch something from the Internet directly.

Comment: @rds you are right, `MediaHttpUploader` isn't relevant for sending emails